# Simplification of a term

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Stuck on a problem about simplifying the term $(x^3-4)^2$. Applying the binomial theorem I'm left with $x^6-2x^3(-4)+16=x^6+8x^3+16.$ Howerver, every online calculator gives $x^6-8x^3+16$ as the correct answer and I did get to that answer by multiplying everything out manually. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The binomial theorem has no minus singns, that means $(x^3-4)^2=x^6+2(-4)x^3+16$.

Comment: I used $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ is that incorrect?

Comment: @dima In that case $b=4$, not $-4$.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to say what you are looking for is how to expand the formula, not simplify it (in this case the final result isn't necessarily "simpler"). Easiest way to do this is rewrite it as: $(x^3-4)(x^3-4)$ and then remember "FOIL" (First, Outside, Inside, Last). Multiply in that order and you get:

$$x^6 - 4x^3 -4x^3 +16$$
Then combine and you get:
$$x^6 - 8x^3 +16$$
Your mistake was when using the formula $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab - b^2$ you assumed that $b = -4$ when it is really $b = 4$. The minus sign in the formula already accounts for that. A little interesting note is that if you had $(x^3+4)^2$ you'd have to rewrite it as $(x^3 -(-4))^2$ to match the formula, and here $b$ would equal $-4$. Honestly, I think it's easier to remember "FOIL" than all the little special cases and exceptions. You just multiply everything by everything (this idea will also work for greater powers like to the power of $3$, but beyond that the binomial theorem is easier to use).